# FBA users should always redirect to Login page

Tags: forms-authentication

How to make sure the FBA users always redirect to login screen before authentication?

My SharePoint site is all setup with FBA authentication and user gets validated also. But before login when they user the URL directly they are able to see the settings page. How to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow Anonymous access to the site. Follow below steps-

> 1. Goto **Site Settings**.
> 2. Select **Site Permissions** under **Users and Permission** section.
> 3. From Ribbon, Click on **Anonymous Access** and then select **Nothing** and Save.

This will not allow anonymous users to visit the site before they login.

Comment: If I do that, all th pages are having 403 forbidden error including the login page which is in unsecuredlayoutbase

Comment: If you are implementing FBA then give it a try..http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent?msg=5138315#xx5138315xx download and install this solution.